# Cross Site Scripting cannot be cleared

Tags: javascript, xss

In order to prevent malicious html/scripts from being entered in input fields and saved in our application, we are inspecting the user input for html and if found, we don't submit.

We do this using the following function

```
    /**
     * Parse for HTML elements to avoid cross-site scripting
     * @param str
     */
    function isHTML() {
        var str = $("#AttributeInstance").val();

        var htmltempElement = document.createElement('div');
        htmltempElement.innerHTML = str;

        for (var c = htmltempElement.childNodes, i = c.length; i--;) {
            if (c[i].nodeType == 1) {
                htmltempElement = null;
                str = null;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

The function is working great. For instance, if on our form, the user enters the following

```
   <img src=a onerror=alert(1)>
```

The function returns true and we don't save the value.

Here is how we call this function

```
            if (isHTML()) {
                alert("Found HTML! Stop!");
                instance = "";
                $("#AttributeInstance").val(""); //clear the input field
            }
            else {
                alert("No HTML! Continue");
                alert(instance);
                addKpi(group, name, instance, instanceSelection);
            }

            alert("Finished");
```

Now here is the issue. This code results in an alert of "Found HTML! Stop!" and then "Finished" being displayed.

But then we also get an alert of "1" which is from the original input value that contains the script. By this point, that field has been cleared and we are not storing the malicious script value anywhere, however, it pops it up as a message even though it was clearly detected and we stop processing.

Any ideas? Or any suggestion how to better detect cross site scripting values in an input field?

If we remove the following from the function

```
    htmltempElement.innerHTML = str;

    for (var c = htmltempElement.childNodes, i = c.length; i--;) {
        if (c[i].nodeType == 1) {
            htmltempElement = null;
            str = null;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Then the script does not pop up the "1" There's something about checking for a script this way that ends up processing the script it seems.

Comment: You are very unlikely to reliably test for malicious code. There will almost certainly be ways around whatever you implement. The best solution to something like this is to always escape user-provided content before displaying it in the browser. That way you don't need to figure out whether it contains malicious code; it won't be executed in any case.

Comment: Client side validation really doesn't stop people from submitting malicious script to your application. It just stops the people from using the interface to do it. You can always use the server side processing of the input to better validate and clean up the code. If using PHP and you don't expect any html to be submitted, `strip_tags` could cover most of the possible malicious code that people could use.